# how to bind on a source property in v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

given [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for) tutorial

as shown below in the code, i am trying to iterate through `items` array and display `item.message`
at run time, i receive the following error:

```
Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
```

please let me know how can i bind on source property in `v-for`

**code**:

```
<template>
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue' 

const items = ref([{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }])

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `:key` in the Vue docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key
To make your life easier just always provide `:key` for `v-for` by selecting some unique value in your objects in the list, in your case it seems `message` since you don't have any `id` property:

```
<template>
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks it is working now...but would you please tell me what the correct appellation of "items" is? is it "source property"

Comment: yes, could be the *source* property for `v-for`, it's an iterable object, like an object or an array. please don't forget to accept my answer and click the checkbox.